# DropDownList in ListView selectedValue always the first one

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding

I have a `ListView` with `DropDownList` inside. I tried both: fill `DropDownList` on `OnItemDataBound` and in `Page_Load`. I also tried checking `PostBack`, but nothing helps.

When I try to get value, I always get the first one. I understand that it is because lists get refilled, but how to avoid it? If I fill them only when `IsPostBack = false`, they became empty.

This is my code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="MyListView">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelWhole %>' /></th>
                <th><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelImport %>' /></th>
                <th><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelPeriod %>' /></th>
                <th><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelDate %>' /></th>
                <th><asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources: Resource, LabelUpload %>' /></th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Whole") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Upload")%></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Period")%></td>
            <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DaysDropDownList"></asp:DropDownList></td>
            <td><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

foreach (var lvItem in MyListView.Items)
{
    if (lvItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DropDownList dr = lvItem.FindControl("DaysDropDownList") as DropDownList;
        for (int i = -1; i >= -12; i--)
        {
            dr.Items.Add(new ListItem(
                DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy MM"),
                DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy MM")));
        }
    }
}
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.DataLayer.LoadData(UserID);
    this.MyListView.DataSource = this.Application.DataLayer.Data;
    this.MyListView.DataBind();

    LoadDropDownLists();
}

private void LoadDropDownLists()
{
    foreach (var lvItem in MyListView.Items)
    {
        if (lvItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            DropDownList dr = lvItem.FindControl("DaysDropDownList") as DropDownList;
            dr.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = -1; i >= -12; i--)
            {
                dr.Items.Add(new ListItem(
                    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy MM"),
                    DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy MM")));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void SubmitButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var lvItem in MyListView.Items)
    {
        if (lvItem.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            DropDownList dr = lvItem.FindControl("DaysDropDownList") as DropDownList;
            FileUpload fl = lvItem.FindControl("FileUpload") as FileUpload;
            if (fl.HasFile)
            {
                string filename = UploadFile(fl, dr.SelectedValue);
                this.Application.DataLayer.SaveUploadRecord(UserID, 0, (int)UploadType.Upload, dr.SelectedValue, filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you populate your DropdownList with ListItem, you can set the ListItem's Selected property accordingly.

Comment: I can't set selected item on databind, because i don't know which item should be selected. In my website user selects item and pressess the button, then i try to get value and i allways get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in which you bind the dropdownlist, Call this function everytime when the page loads(in the page_load event), but before calling it first clear the existing dropdownlist datasource.

Comment: I just tried that and it does not work. I get the same result.