# How to build a ListView and fill it from the codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fill my `ListView` from codebehind *and* want to know how to build the fields.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11407221/1919644) example, and I'd like to now if the only way to build a `ListView`s fields is using tables. If not, what would be another way to do that?  I tried only filling the `ListView` with datasource, like this:

```
ListView1.DataSource = ds;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

But it gave me an error:

> An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'ListView1'.

What is the best way to use `ListView`?  The error happens only when I use `ListView1.DataBind();`

PS: I'll need only **one** row to display, so if someone has a better control to use than `ListView`, I'm reading.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm trying like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
       <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
           <tr style="background-color: #E5E5FE">
              <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResp" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
              <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProj" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
              <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFunc" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
              <th<></th>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
          <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblResp"><%#Eval("responsavel") %></asp:Label></td>
          <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProj"><%#Eval("projeto") %></asp:Label></td>
          <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFunc"><%#Eval("funcionalidade") %></asp:Label></td>
       </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But I got a **new** error:

`An item placeholder must be specified on ListView 'ListView1'.

Specify an item placeholder by setting a control's ID property to "itemPlaceholder".

The item placeholder control must also specify runat="server".`

Comment: "*But it gave me an error*" - Please always show the actual error text when you post questions.  What was the error?  Which line threw the error?

Comment: "an error" is a little bit vague. Could you give more details ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  
Question Updated. Sorry, I was debuging to copy the error message. Could you please remove the downvote?

Comment: @Ghaleon I don't downvote when asking for details ;)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Updated my question with the error... It happens only when I use `DataBind();` without it, nothing happens, the `listview` does not shows and no error happens ;\ Could you please remove the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for adding the information, downvote removed.  Please post complete questions in the future =)

Answer (score 4):

In your `LayoutTemplate`, you need a `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />` in the `table` tag.

```
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="1">
       <tr style="background-color: #E5E5FE">
          <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResp" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
          <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProj" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
          <th align="left"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFunc" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></th>
          <th<></th>
       </tr>
       <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
   </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```